# Class will initialize when in loop(), but not in setup()

Tags: loops, class, arduino, installation, instance

I created a class in Arduino and brought in the class. Code compiles and runs fine when:

```
#include <myclass.h>

void setup(){
// Do some setup if needed
}

void loop(){
myclass newInstance;
newInstance.setSomething();
newInstance.getSomething();
}
```

But doesn't verify/compile when:

```
#include <myclass.h>

void setup(){
myclass newInstance;
newInstance.setSomething();
}

void loop(){
newInstance.getSomething();
}
```

Error: 'newInstance' was not declared in this scope.

I've seen some people instantiate outside of the setup and loop (right below the include section). Please explain the best practices for creating an instance and then using it in the loop. I want to instantiate outside the loop section so I'm not creating an instance each loop.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that I don't like Arduino framework forcing to use two separate "main" functions with no benefit that I can see... They are two different scopes, whatever you declared in one, will not be visible for the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the object in the global scope. The variable declaration in C++ (and Arduinos' language is basically C++) is valid in the [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

So your code should look like

```
#include <myclass.h>

myclass newInstance;

void setup(){

newInstance.setSomething();
}

void loop(){
newInstance.getSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but was including the ".setsomething" in the global. It works when I just create an instance in the global like you have. This is the correct answer.

Comment: The code in the global scope is not running, only defining variables. You should place executable code in the functions. In Arduino all starts in predefined functions `setup` and `loop`, in other environments usually in function `main`